# Arguing a stationary distribution exists

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I am trying to show that there exists a stationary distribution when $q>p$ for the Markov process with one-step transition matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
q  & p     & 0     &   0     & \dots     & 0  \\
q  & 0 & p & 0 &  \dots      & \dots \\
0 & q & 0 & p & \dots & \dots   \\
0  & 0 & q & 0 & \dots & \dots \\
\vdots  & \vdots       & \vdots & q & \dots & \dots \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\dots& \dots& \\
0 & 0     & 0    & 0    & \ddots     & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But, observing each resulting equality like 
\begin{align*}
q\pi_{0} + q \pi_{1} &= \pi_{0} \\
p \pi_{0} + q \pi_{2} &= \pi_{1} \\
\dots
\end{align*}

I cannot establish a general pattern for each $\pi_{i}$ and then prove that they sum to $1$. Where am I going wrong? Or rather, am I just missing a pattern? It seems to be a formula that does not have a pattern.

Comment: The entries in the last row of your matrix don't add up to one.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Oh no, I miswrote it. It is just supposed to continue like a normal random walk for the positive integers, one moment I'll edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algebra is straightforward. We know $\pi P=\pi$ must be satisfied. The first equation gives us $\pi_1q=\pi_0p$. Take the equation: $\pi_2 q+\pi_0p=\pi_1$. A simplification gives us $\pi_2=(p/q)^2\pi_0$. Continuing this way, in general, you get: $\pi_k=(p/q)^k \pi_0$.

Summing up the $\pi$s to 1, you will find $\pi_0=1-p/q$. The other probabilities can be evaluated from this.